# Regex Dot to End of Line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I have a txt document with too many lines. What I want to do is a bit complicated. For example, I want to reach the end of each line containing the word thing and put a period there. But only at the end of the lines that contain the word thing.

Example : [regexr.com/64ehm](https://regexr.com/64ehm)

Comment: Use this: `^(thing)$` See Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zrzI61/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the regular expression you could use to do that is quite simple. This, along with the *global* and *multiline* flags, would match lines that contain only the word thing:

```
^Thing$
```

If you don't want to distinguish uppercase from lowercase letters, the *case insensitive* flag can help you.

After getting the lines you're looking for, you can use the means available in your programming language or tool to put a period at each line's end.

You can also [test that regular expression in RegExr](http://regexr.com/64eh4).

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well, sorry for that. I think I'll explain it better in this example. How can I put a period at the end of elements that contain only thing from the word list in the example. regexr.com/64ehm

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: I've edited my answer and my RegExr pattern. According to your example, I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```js
let text = `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipisicing elit, thing sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
`;

text = text.replace(/\b[Tt]hing\b.*/g, '$&.');

console.log(text);
```

`\b` means assert word boundary.

`$&` is a special pattern that represents whatever was matched by the regex. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).